# Edit an element in a list - python

Tags: python, list, csv, for-loop

i have written a program that take row from an excel spreadsheet and returns them as lists. i am no trying to edit each list that is created:

***...from***

```
['-1', '3', '4', '5', '3', '7', '2', '4', '0', '8', '12', '23', '4', '0']
```

***to...***

```
['-1', '1:3', '2:4', '3:5', '4:3', '5:7', '6:2', '7:4', '8:0', '9:8', '10:12', '11:23', '12:4', '13:0']
```

```python
import csv

with open('testingSeta.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    line = True

    for row in reader:
        if line:
            line = False
            continue

        x = row.pop()
        row.insert(0,x)        

        print(row)
```

Comment: No idea what your question is

Comment: Couldn't you just use [`list.map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)?

Comment: Please explain your logic. What is the **relationship** between those two lists supposed to be?

Comment: it takes the values from the rows in the excel spreadsheet and put it into a list in python. for example the first list is from row 1 in excel. the second list represent an edit version of the first list. im trying to add 1:x, 2:y... etc to the values in the list without losing the value that was there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['-1', '3', '4', '5', '3', '7', '2', '4', '0', '8', '12', '23', '4', '0']
>>> a[:1] + ["{}:{}".format(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(a[1:], start=1)]
['-1', '1:3', '2:4', '3:5', '4:3', '5:7', '6:2', '7:4', '8:0', '9:8', '10:12', '11:23', '12:4', '13:0']
```

[Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) give you access of index and element as tuple

Using `itertools.starmap`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a[:1] + list(itertools.starmap("{}:{}".format, enumerate(a[1:], start=1)))
['-1', '1:3', '2:4', '3:5', '4:3', '5:7', '6:2', '7:4', '8:0', '9:8', '10:12', '11:23', '12:4', '13:0']
```

Using `map` and `lambda`:

```
>>> a[:1] + map(lambda x:"{}:{}".format(x[0],x[1]), enumerate(a[1:], start=1))
['-1', '1:3', '2:4', '3:5', '4:3', '5:7', '6:2', '7:4', '8:0', '9:8', '10:12', '11:23', '12:4', '13:0']
```

if you want to store it:

```
>>> a = a[:1] + ["{}:{}".format(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(a[1:], start=1)]
>>> print(a)
['-1', '1:3', '2:4', '3:5', '4:3', '5:7', '6:2', '7:4', '8:0', '9:8', '10:12', '11:23', '12:4', '13:0']
```

Comment: you can start the index at 1 and remove the x+1  
`a[:1] + ["{}:{}".format(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(a[1:],1)]`

Comment: yeaaa sure @PadraicCunningham

Comment: doesnt seem to work. when i then print (a) it just prints the original list.

Comment: check the update  the last one , @goosingout

Answer (score 1):

Try with list comprehension:

```
src =  ['-1', '3', '4', '5', '3', '7', '2', '4', '0', '8', '12', '23', '4', '0']


src[0:1] + [ str(i+1) + ":" + v for i,v in enumerate(src[1:])]
```

Which results in:

```
['-1',
'1:3',
'2:4',
'3:5',
'4:3',
'5:7',
'6:2',
'7:4',
'8:0',
'9:8',
'10:12',
'11:23',
'12:4',
'13:0']
```

You can also use a functional approach as:

```
map(lambda (i,v): v if i == 0 else str(i)+":"+v, enumerate(src))
```

I do prefer the functional way but, as far as I know, list comprehesion seems to be more "pythonic".

Comment: Call using `f(src)`: `f=lambda l:map(lambda (i,v): ('' if i==0 else str(i)+":")+v, enumerate(l))`

Answer (score 0):

```
from_list = ['-1', '3', '4', '5', '3', '7', '2', '4', '0', '8', '12', '23', '4', '0']

for i in range(1, len(from_list)):

    new_ele = str(i)+':'+from_list[i]
    from_list[i] = new_ele
print from_list
```

the output would be:

```
['-1', '1:3', '2:4', '3:5', '4:3', '5:7', '6:2', '7:4', '8:0', '9:8', '10:12', '11:23', '12:4', '13:0']
```